# ASP.NET Core 2 with Razor: Populating a select list

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to populate a select list from a viewbag but it is not populating. I have 68 items in the viewbag (using a breakpoint) so I know the data is there. I am obviously using the wrong format for getting the data from the viewbag. My problem could be

```
asp-for="CountyId"
```

Here is my code...

CHTML

`<select asp-for="CountyId" data-live-search="true" class="selectpicker" asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.ListofCounty, "CountyId", "CountyName"))"></select>`

Controller

```
    public IActionResult Index(TblCounty TblCounty) {
        List<TblCounty> countylist = new List<TblCounty>();

        // ----------- Getting Data from Database Using Entity FrameworkCore ----------- //
        countylist = (from product in _context.TblCounty
                      select product).ToList();

        // ----------- Inserting Select Item in List ----------- //
        countylist.Insert(0, new TblCounty { CountyId = 0, CountyName = "Select" });

        // ----------- Assigning countylist to View.ListofCounty ----------- //
        ViewBag.ListofCounty = countylist;

        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the best way but it works great!

```
<select class="selectpicker">
    @foreach (var county in ViewBag.ListofCounty)
    {
        <option value="@county.CountyId">@county.CountyName</option>
    }
</select>
```